# How can I 2-way databind to a livedata<POJO> members?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, two-way-binding

I am trying to two way databind from a checkbox to a mutable livedata variable in my viewModel that's a POJO(plain old java object). It's a Time POJO that has a thru boolean.

I've tried setting up the view in xml to 2 way bind to the data variable 
@=(modelview.mTime.blnThru) and I've also set up a text box to show me the string value of that same boolean. When I click the checkbox on and off the string value doesn't change.

I've tested this w/ a standard mutableLiveData replacing the original bindings with this test set and now when i toggle it on and off, the text value properly shows true and false. So I know I'm on the right track.

```
<CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/Thru_CheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Days Thru"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ToTime_Add_Button"
        android:checked="@={viewmodel.mTime.blnThru}"/>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{String.valueOf(viewmodel.mTime.blnThru)}"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="104dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="316dp" />
```

View model variable declaration

```
val test = MutableLiveData<Boolean>().apply { this.value = false }
var mTime = MutableLiveData<Time>()
...

init{
        mTime.value = Time()
...}
```

I just want to know what I'm needing to do extra so that I can get rid of my event trigger code in my fragment.

Thanks in advance!